GRUB-2.06 verify_detached error: bad signature
I am not sure if this is the correct platform for grub but one thing know for sure is a-lot of experts are here who can guide me better. I am experimenting with verifying few files in grub.cfg. I have a file (myfile.elf) and followed commands from here to generate detached signatures.
mkdir --mode 0700 keys
gpg --homedir keys --gen-key
gpg --homedir keys --export-secret-keys --armor > boot.secret.key # backup
gpg --homedir keys --export > boot.keys
gpg --homedir keys --detach-sign myfile.elf

in my grub.cfg i loaded the key to add it to trusted keys and tried to verify the signature but with all combinations, it fails.
trust --skip-sig boot.keys (#even tried in .gpg format)
list_trusted (# I see a key)
verify_detached myfile.elf.sig myfile.elf  (paths are valid)

When I try to verify the file using:
gpg --verify myfile.elf.sig myfile.elf

it gives, good signature but in grub shell and grub.cfg i see "error: Bad Signature".
I tried keys in .asc, .gpg, .key format but couldn't make it working. Even imported my exported keys and tried the above gpg command to verify if the key is proper.
Looking forward to experts guidance, please.
